# How do I add a QPushButton to PyQtGraph using addItem?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I am trying to add a button at the bottom of two plots that will display data to read in from a file. Underneath these two plots will be a button to control an action. I have attempted to add a widget, layout, graphicsItem from the pyqt library. 
I can easily add a label to the layout but when adding a button I get the following error

```
addItem(self, QGraphicsLayoutItem, int, int, alignment: Union[Qt.Alignment, Qt.AlignmentFlag] = Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QPushButton'
```

The code being tested:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg

win = pg.GraphicsWindow()

win.setWindowTitle('Test App')
label = pg.LabelItem(justify='right')
win.addItem(label)

button = QtGui.QPushButton()

p1 = win.addPlot(row=0, col=0)
p2 = win.addPlot(row=1, col=0)
p3 = win.addLayout(row=2, col=0)
p3.addItem(button,row=1,col=1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pyqtgraph documentation on [addItem](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/plotitem.html#pyqtgraph.PlotItem.addItem) states that it "adds a graphics item to the view box."

The thing is, a `QtPushButton` is not a graphic item, it's a widget. Therefore the error: `addItem` is expecting a `QGraphicsLayoutItem` (or something that inherits that class), and you're passing a `QWidget`

To add a widget into a `GraphicsWindow`, you could wrap it with `QGraphicsProxyWidget`

```
proxy = QtGui.QGraphicsProxyWidget()
button = QtGui.QPushButton('button')
proxy.setWidget(button)

p3 = win.addLayout(row=2, col=0)
p3.addItem(proxy,row=1,col=1)
```

But depending on what you need to do, you might want to implement a PyQt GUI, with the `GraphicsWindow` being one element of this GUI. This question could help you: [How to update a realtime plot and use buttons to interact in pyqtgraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056635/how-to-update-a-realtime-plot-and-use-buttons-to-interact-in-pyqtgraph)

Answer (score 3):

The other answer still holds, but since 0.13, `QGraphicsWindow` has been removed. You are supposed to use `QGraphicsLayoutWidget` instead.

Dear future me, (and dear other who might find this useful), please find below a working code sample to add a simple button to a graph.

```py
import numpy as np

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtWidgets, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg


def onButtonClicked():
    pg.plot(np.random.random(100))


win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()

plot = win.addPlot()
# Or specify the position
# plot = win.addPlot(row=0, col=0)
plot.plot(np.random.random(100))

btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Show another graph")
btn.clicked.connect(onButtonClicked)
proxy = QtWidgets.QGraphicsProxyWidget()
proxy.setWidget(btn)
win.addItem(proxy)
# Or specify the position
# plot = win.addItem(proxy, row=0, col=0)

win.show()
pg.exec()
```